# Would anyone know why css is not working in my html?

Tags: html, css

Would anyone know why css is not working in my html? It is linked to my html, but not working. It is also showing empty in chrome inspect - css tab. I see that css is linking , but not sure why it is not working.. Thank you in advance!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Quierra Marriott</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
```

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 10px
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #eee;``
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url() no-repeat center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Check the path of your css file if it is in the same directory as index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing semicolon and empty string are problem but they are only affecting font-size property of html selector.

If your intention was to add background to body then you should fill image url

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('http://image-url.com/image') no-repeat center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

These is main reason for empty page

Answer (score 4):

Your css is invalid:

```
html {
    font-size: 10px /* You're missing a semi-colon here*/
    color: #eee;`` /* You don't need the strings `` here...*/
...
```

It may be of interest to you to find a tool like w3c css validator: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/.

Answer (score -2):

Didn't see any 'body' tag in your HTML that's why I think it's not working

Comment: he simpy didnt share it. As he has also not closing HTML tag... Think beyond what he posted espacially when its obvios. However right anwser where given that his CSS is was incorrectly written.